# How do I change the default Chrome tab page?

Tags: google-chrome

How do I change the default new tab page in Google Chrome (version 41 on Win 8.1).

I want it to point to an HTML page on my own computer - the same page in fact as I am using for my home page.

Answer (score 12):

You can use a plugin

This extension does it

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/new-tab-redirect/icpgjfneehieebagbmdbhnlpiopdcmna

If the link dies, then search for "New Tab Redirect Chrome plugin"

Comment: The extension does the trick nicely. Many thanks.

P.S. Can anyone tell me why Google have chosen to be so irritating?
When you think of all the free stuff that Google offer us in order to try to make us like/appreciate them, I find it bizarre.

Comment: I don't want to use and extension because I don't trust them. Would I have to make my own extension?

Comment: I'm with @E.V.I.L. Interestingly Google advertise all its products on this page that you can't change at this moment. Very monopolistic.

Answer (score 0):

Really does look like you have to create or use an extension. Here's some info on how to do it, if you already [know how to write an extension](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted), from the [Mozilla Dev Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/chrome_url_overrides), strangely enough.

> Use the chrome_url_overrides key to provide a custom replacement for the documents loaded into various special pages usually provided by the browser itself.
>
> `newtab`
>   Provide a replacement for the document that's shown in the "new tab" page. This is the page that's shown when the user has opened a new tab but has not loaded any document into it: for example, by using the Ctrl/Command+T keyboard shortcut.

I dug through the [Empty New Tab Page extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/empty-new-tab-page/dpjamkmjmigaoobjbekmfgabipmfilij) a bit, and it provides a good template for doing this sort of thing.

Answer (score -4):

From [Chrome Help: Set your homepage and startup page](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95314?hl=en)

> #### Choose your homepage (Tab Page)
>
> You can control what page appears when you click in the top left of
> your screen the Home button.
>
> - Open Chrome.
> - In the top-right corner, click the icon you see: Menu Menu or More More.
> - Select Settings.
> - Under "Appearance," check the box Show Home button.
> - Below "Show Home button," click Change to choose your homepage.
>
> The Home button will appear to the left of your address bar.

Comment: When copying content from elsewhere on the internet you should provide attribution. Please read [How to reference material written by others](http://superuser.com/help/referencing).

Comment: Not a correct answer to this question, since it doesn't change the new tab page.